# Should I use an empty property key?

Tags: javascript

I've tested this only in Firefox, but apparently you can use an empty string as a key to a property in an object. For example, see the first property here:

```
var countsByStatus = { 
  "": 23, //unknown status
  "started": 45,
  "draft": 3,
  "accepted": 23,
  "hold": 2345,
  "fixed": 2,
  "published": 345
}
```

In skimming through the EcmaScript specs, it appears that (at least in 5), property keys are defined as strings, and strings as 0 or more characters. This implies that an empty string is a valid property name according to the specs.

Anyway, I'm tempted to use this in a section of code where I'm calculating summaries of some counts by the status of a data item (similar to what I've shown above). There are some items which might not have a status, and I need a placeholder for those. Since statuses are user-definable, I don't want to risk using a dummy word that might conflict.

It seems so simple and elegant, in looking at the data I can easily tell what the blank string would mean. It also makes the code a little bit more efficient, since the empty string would be the exact value of the status in the items without a status.

But at the same time, my instincts are telling me that something is wrong with it. I mean, apart from the chance that some browser might not support this, I feel like I've encountered a bug in JavaScript that will be fixed some day. But, at the same time, that's the same feeling I once had about a lot of other JavaScript features that I now use every day (such as the time I discovered that && and || returns the value of one of the operands, not just true or false).

Comment: associative arrays in most languages store the index keys as hashes, and even an empty string will hash to something, e.g. `md5('') == d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

Comment: *"my instincts are telling me that something is wrong with it."* Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Great question. Just checked: Works in python too. I'd say go for it.

Comment: Only downside I can see is that you know what `""` is, but others who might pick up and work on your code might not. Personally I would use some sort of descriptive word which would be more...well...descriptive. e.g. "placeholder" as you mentioned in your description.

Comment: Okay, to be clear, I'm asking for whether using an empty string as a key will be compatible across browsers and into future versions of JS. Although the answers which discuss the aesthetic decision as to whether to use them are great answers, and made me think a little, I can't really choose them as the correct answer.

Comment: Nice question - stuff like this is why StackOverflow is awesome.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An object's key must be a string, and the empty string (`''`) *is* a string. There is no cross browser issue that I've ever come across with empty strings, although there have been very few occasions where I thought it was acceptable to use an empty string as a key name.

I would *discourage* the general usage of `''` as a key, but for a simple lookup, it'll work just fine, and sounds reasonable. It's a good place to add a comment noting the exceptional circumstance.

Additionally, during lookup you may have issues with values that are cast to a string:

```
o = {...} //some object
foo = 'bar';

//some examples
o[foo] //will return o['bar']
o[null] //will return o['null']
o[undefined] //will return o['undefined']
```

If you'd like to have `null` and `undefined` use the `''` key, you may need to use a fallback:

```
key = key || '';
```

If you might have non-string values passed in, it's important to cast too:

```
key = key || '';
key = '' + key;
```

note that a value of `0` will turn into `''`, whereas a value of `'0'` will stay `'0'`.

---

In most cases, I find I'm picking a pre-defined value out of a <del>hashtable</del> object. To check that the value exists on the object there are a number of options:

```
//will be falsey if the value is falsey
if (o[key]) {...}

//will return true for properties on the object as well as in the prototype hierarchy
if (key in o) {...}

//returns true only for properties on the object instance
if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very detailed answer, with some helpful hints.

Comment: I think `key = '' + key;` will turn `0` into  `'0'`

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado, yes: `key = '' + 0` will turn into `'0'`, but that's not what I wrote. `key = 0 || ''` will give `key` a value of `''`, which will then be cast to a string.

Answer (score 12):

Technically, there is nothing wrong and you can savely use it on any js engine (that I'm aware of). Since ECMAscripts spec says any object key is a *string*, it of course can also be an empty string.

The only caveat is, that you'll never be able to access that property with the dot notation

```
countsByStatus.;
```

will lead to a syntax error of course, so it always needs to be

```
countsByStatus[''];
```

That much about the technical part. If we talk about the convinient part, I'd vote for a very clear **no**, never use it.

It'll lead to confusion and as we all know, *confusion is the enemy*.

Comment: Another way to avoid confusion is to add a prefix to the keys like "st_". This avoids potential name clashes (esp. with built-in properties) and solves the can't use dot problem.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Yes, when I do things like this, I always make sure they are fully commented. I'd also like to point out that this data structure is restricted to one enclosed object, and it has methods which make it so that other objects which work with this don't ever have to know how it's storing "no status" data. (Which also makes it easier to change if I decide to someday).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that since the statuses are user-defineable there is nothing stoping the user from *also* using the empty string as a status, thus ruining your logic. From this point of view what you are doing is no different then just using an ugly custom name like `__$$unknown_status`. (Well, I'd say the ugly custom name is more descriptive but to each its own...)

If you want to be really sure the "unknown" property does not collide you need to keep it separate:

```
var counts = {
    unknownStatus: 23,
    byStatus: {
        "": 17, //actual status with no name, (if this makes sense)
        "started": 45,
        "draft": 3,
        "accepted": 23,
        "hold": 2345,
        "fixed": 2,
        "published": 345
    }
};
```

Comment: @RightSaidFred: I don't know, I think I just focused more on the "should I use" rather then the "can I use"

Comment: Well, I guess I don't see a *"should I"* part of the question that relates to application logic. Anyway as far as we know, there's some validation requirement for statuses where `""` would be disallowed. Also, I don't see how `unknownStatus:` would be better since you still don't know what the intent was, so the user still can't really use `""`.

Comment: I'm just curious to know how OP distinguishes between `unknownStatus` and `status === ""`.

Comment: Sure, right now, there's nothing to stop a user from specifying a blank status. However, and this may be a topic for another conversation, in this application, I don't see any semantic difference *in English* between having no status and having a blank status. In fact, in the UI, the difference between the two would be barely discernible (I think the null gets a tiny placeholder image, that's it). From a user standpoint, at least in this case, I would expect my leaving the status blank to mean the same as not having a status.

Comment: However, I'm still going to upvote your answer, since it brings up a really valid point, and made me stop briefly to reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ok.  `""` has semantics in your application, and its valid javascript. So have at it.

Note that

`x."" = 2;`

will error out, so you need to use syntax like

`x[""] = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Is "unknown status" a null value or is your status field "not null"?

In the first case I'd say you will have to use a separate counter, in the second I'd say that "empty" is a perfectly valid status - just use the word "unknown" for output instead of "". This might only lead to confusion when your user uses the same word as a status type, but to prevent that you only can use a different visual style for "unknown status" output text.