# Can I use an empty string as an object identifier?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been tinkering with objects and seemingly you can have '' (an empty string) as a property name, like so:

```
o = {
    '':    'hello',
    1:     'world',
    'abc': ':-)',
};
console.log(o['']);
```

Seems to work just fine, however I'm curious to know, **is this really valid?** I've poked at the ECMA specs and asked our ever-knowledgeable friend Google variations of the question and my conclusion is that *I don't know*.

**My sources**

http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

Comment: I think it is valid because it's also a string, so it doesn't matter if the string contains something or not. But I think it isn't save to rely on such a thing because eventually some day this could change...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, technically its totally valid and you can safely use it. An object key needs to be a "string", which does not exclude an empty string.

If that is convenient or even useful is another story.

See [Should I use an empty property key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343938/should-i-use-an-empty-property-key)

---

Since the 'empty string' is one of the `falsy values` in ecmascript, consider the following example:

```
var foo = {
    ':-)': 'face',
    'answer': 42,
    '': 'empty'
};

Object.keys( foo ).forEach(function( key ) {
    if( key ) {
        console.log(key);
    }
});
```

That snippet would only log `:-)` and `answer`. So that is one pitfall for doing this.

Comment: Very true, as would a property numerical 0

Comment: This is kinda artifical, because w/o if (key) it logs all the properties in question

Comment: @oodavid: infact, `0` would not be a problem. Since all object keys are **strings** the outcome would be `"0"`, which again is not a falsy value.

Comment: @oodavid, cannot be, properties are strings, so "0"

Comment: @user539484: indeed, I just wanted to demonstrate the potential danger in doing this.

Comment: @user539484 - You wouldn't do an `if(key)` right inside a `forEach` (or `for..in`) loop. But I think that's just an example; you might have some more complicated code that sets `key` in some other way where potentially it really doesn't get set and an `if(key)` test might be necessary. (Of course, you can still work around that with `if (key===undefined)`...)

Comment: @nnnnnn, properties are strings again, `undefined` cannot be :) eg: `{"undefined":"HAI"}`

Comment: @user539484 - No, I wasn't saying the object would have a property with the name `undefined`, I was saying you might have a variable, `key`, that depending on program logic could hold either an actual property name or the value `undefined`, and in that case if you said `if(key)` you wouldn't know the difference between `key===""` and `key===undefined`.

Comment: furthermore, its not so unusual that people check for existing properties in a way like `if( obj.key )`. That would be another case where we have a false-positive.

Comment: @jAndy, but in our case that would become `var obj = {'':42}; if (obj['']) alert('PASS'); else alert('FAIL');` which **passes**.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, but when `undefined` will become a *property*, it will be coerced toString, eg `alert(JSON.stringify({undefined:'HAI'}))`

Comment: @user539484 - In the situation I'm describing `undefined` would never become a property name. Read my last comment again a couple of times - you seem to be arguing about something else. And +1 to jAndy for putting up with all this.

Comment: @nnnnnn, so you finally realized what i and jAndy were *discussing* something else before you appeared with your `undefined` statements? :-)

Comment: @user539484 - I thought I was part of the discussion. My comments related directly to the code in jAndy's answer. I agreed with your original comment that jAndy's example seemed artificial, so I gave a real-world example where the _same_ problem would occur. It's not a _big_ problem because it's easy to avoid, but in each of your replies to me you misunderstood what I was talking about.

Comment: @jAndy, ah! Got your point and what do you check with `if (obj[prop])` statement. IMO, its highly fragile because its quite common case when **value** of empty-string-property is falsy itself. Of course its much better to use `if (prop in obj)` instead.

Comment: @nnnnnn, perhaps PASS/FAIL style code snippet (see above) would help, then... I'd really like to learn which else dangers empty-string-property could carry (out of curiousity, ofc)

Comment: Oh very interesting indeed; I hadn't realised that all properties would be coerced into being strings (quite obvious looking at the first line of @jAndy's response.

Answer (score 5):

[Seems fine](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) (the `(*)` apply to your case):

```
PropertyAssignment :
    (*) PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
    get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody } 
    set PropertyName ( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }

PropertyName :
    IdentifierName
    (*) StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral

StringLiteral ::
    " DoubleStringCharacters opt "
    (*) ' SingleStringCharacters opt '
```

Since the characters are optional, an empty string is valid.

Just note that `IdentifierName` (i.e. without `'` or `"`) does not allow an empty string:

```
IdentifierName ::
    IdentifierStart
    IdentifierName IdentifierPart

IdentifierStart ::
    UnicodeLetter
    $
    _ 
    \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
```

So, `{'': 123}` is valid whereas `{: 123}` is not.